# Pegar valor CheckBox de um formulário como boolean para outro formulario

Tags: delphi

Tenho um `checkbox` em um formulário e quero receber o valor dele em outro formulário como `boolean`, por exemplo: `CheckBox1.Checked = true` quero receber como valor `1`, e `CheckBox1.Checked = false` quero receber como valor `0`

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `Integer()` para converter um `Boolean` para `Integer`, depois multiplico por `-1` por que o retorno dessa função quando `CheckBox1.Checked` for `True` é `-1` e não `1`:

```
var
  resInt: Integer;
begin
  resInt := Integer(CheckBox1.Checked) * -1;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta assim

```
if SeuForm.CheckBox1.Checked = False then
  SuaVar := 0
else 
  SuaVar := 1;
```

Lembre de por na `implementation` `uses` a ***unit*** do *Form* onde está a `TCheckBox1`

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses USua_Unit_do_Form, ...;
```